# Highcharts - Y axis colors by point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I configure the y axis so that it has different colors?

From this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeToS.png)

[image]

To this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU4JW.png)

[image]

JSFIDDLE:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        lineWidth: 2
    },
```

Maybe someone had a similar problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-basic/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by setting `yAxis.lineColor` as `Highcharts.GradientColorObject`. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        let chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

        yAxis.update({
          lineColor: {
            linearGradient: [chart.plotLeft + yAxis.width, 0, 0, 0],
            stops: [
              [0, 'yellow'],
              [0.33, 'yellow'],
              [0.33, 'red'],
              [0.66, 'red'],
              [0.66, '#21B04C'],
              [1, '#21B04C']
            ]
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania']
  },
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 4
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Year 1900',
    data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
  }, {
    name: 'Year 2000',
    data: [814, 841, 3714, 727, 31]
  }, {
    name: 'Year 2016',
    data: [1216, 1001, 4436, 738, 40]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7feLmsvq/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.lineColor
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.GradientColorObject